# Storing css an graphics outside .asar

Tags: electron, electron-packager

I have an Electron App that - when used - needs to be packed as asar. On the other Hand CSS and graphics sometimes need to be changed while in use. Therefore I need to exclude some of the Files from packaging via `--ignore`parameter and copy the unpacked Files manually into the Folder so I can change them easily. For that all of the Paths to my CSS need to be rewritten of course.

But then the App does not work in my development environment because those paths do not exist if not packed.

Does anybody know a Solution where I can access my CSS and graphic files in both environments - packed and unpacked?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [electron-is-dev](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-is-dev) to check if the app is running in a development environment or if it's in production. You would then use the file path that corresponds.

Something along the lines of:

```
const isDev = require('electron-is-dev')

if (isDev) {
  //use development path (unpacked)
} else {
  // use production path (packed)
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea for JS files, but has it's limits. My CSS files are referenced in the HTML head, things like background graphics inside the CSS files where i cannot use JS.

Comment: You could have 2 files, one file with each path and use once for development and the other for production. The downside is you would have to maintain each copy individually. You could create a small script that watches one file and updates the other while changing the paths.

Comment: That is what I tried to avoid. There are a couple of CSS files that are changed on a nearly daily basis - maintaining them separated will lead to errors.